# SQL Job Step - different job owner and step user

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to start steps under security context of user (execute as), but it's not working when job owner is different user than "Run as user".

Executed as user: XXXX. The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysschedules', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229).  The step failed.

But even grant select for msdb objects sysschedules, sysjobs, sysjobactivity didn't work. Even server sysadmin role didn't work. Event adding into role SQLAgentUserRole, SQLAgentReaderRole or/and SQLAgentOperatorRole didn't work. Still the same error.

What are **minimal** permissions/roles for **user** to execute t-sql step where job is owned by different user?

```
execute as user = N'USERNAME' -- not working
select count(*) from msdb.dbo.sysschedules
```

User is member of db_owner. User have permission control, select... on dbo schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem when I'd like to select from msdb.dbo.sysschedules but from my database. User exists on database msdb too. Problem was fixed by adding option `TRUSTWORTHY Database property` - now can the same user from my database be used in msdb.

Whole problem was based on procedure `msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep` parameter `@database_user_name` - it's not login, but only user.

[TRUSTWORTHY Database property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/trustworthy-database-property?view=sql-server-2017)